# Strange behaviour of bash date and time arithmetics

Tags: bash, time

When I issue bash command:

```
date --date="2018-03-03 12:16:13 -1hour" "+%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S"
```

I expect the result would be:

```
2018:03:03 11:16:13
```

but instead, I get:

```
2018:03:03 15:16:13
```

I wonder if this has to make with time zones, and how to avoid this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `info coreutils 'date invocation'`

> When a relative item causes the resulting date to cross a boundary where the clocks were adjusted, typically for daylight saving time,
>   the resulting date and time are adjusted accordingly.
>
> The fuzz in units can cause problems with relative items.  For
>   example, '2003-07-31 -1 month' might evaluate to 2003-07-01, because
>   2003-06-31 is an invalid date.  To determine the previous month more
>   reliably, you can ask for the month before the 15th of the current
>   month.  For example:
>
> ```
>  $ date -R
>  Thu, 31 Jul 2003 13:02:39 -0700
>  $ date --date='-1 month' +'Last month was %B?'
>  Last month was July?
>  $ date --date="$(date +%Y-%m-15) -1 month" +'Last month was %B!'
>  Last month was June!
> ```
>
> Also, take care when manipulating dates around clock changes such
>   as daylight saving leaps.  In a few cases these have added or
>   subtracted as much as 24 hours from the clock, so it is often wise to
>   adopt universal time by setting the 'TZ' environment variable to
>   'UTC0' before embarking on calendrical calculations.

One can avoid that by putting `-1 hour` before the string,

```
$ date --date='-1 hour 2018-03-03 12:16:13' "+%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S"
2018:03:03 11:16:13
```

Answer (score 5):

I can reproduce this. My timezone is America/New_York

```
$ date --date="2018-03-03 12:16:13 - 1 hour" "+%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S"
2018:03:03 09:16:13
$ env TZ='Europe/Belgrade' date --date="2018-03-03 12:16:13 - 1 hour" "+%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S"
2018:03:03 15:16:13
```

The parser appears to be taking the `-1` as the timezone GMT+01:00, then converting *that* to your local timezone.

If we rearrange the phrases to avoid the timezone parsing ambiguity, we can get your desired result:

```
$ date --date="- 1 hour 2018-03-03 12:16:13" "+%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S"
2018:03:03 11:16:13
```